# IIS error "the site administrator has locked access to this section"

Tags: asp.net, iis

Parser Error Message: This configuration section cannot be used at this path.  This happens when the site administrator has locked access to this section using  from an inherited configuration file.

Source Error:

```
Line 29:     <customErrors mode="Off" />
Line 30:   </system.web>
Line 31:   <system.webServer>    <--- Error
Line 32:     <modules>
Line 33:       <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
```

For the whole Web.config please click at [this link](https://pastebin.com/vnC4MFXN). I replaced some sensitive names by "...".

I'm new to .net and IIS. What should I do to resolve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use Stack Exchange to ask this question (and put the whole web.config; not just a few lines)

Comment: @Felix Thanks, I have added it

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I couldn't see your web.config completely. 
Perhaps you can check **IIS Manager -> Feature Delegation** to ensure required permissions for features which you used are configured by **Read/Write**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. web.config is in a link.

Comment: I have checked it. All delegations are Read/Write